# Retrieve a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, correlation

Here is a little mathematical problem, and please pardon my lack of vocabulary to describe it.

Let be a real function $x(t)$ (it can be a position as a function of time, for example).

Now from this 1D function, I build a new function $u(t_{1},t_{2})$, built from the value of $x(t)$ at two times $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$:

$u(t_{1},t_{2})=e^{-(x(t_{1})-x(t_{2}))^2}$

which is then a 2D function (here is my lack of vocabulary, there must be a name for this kind of operation).

If you are given $x(t)$, $u(t_{1},t_{2})$ is quite simple to find. Now my question is, if you are given $u(t_{1},t_{2})$, how can you retreive the original function $x(t)$?

Comment: You must know one value of $x$. Otherwise you can't distinguish between $x(t)$ and $x(t)+C$.

Comment: The answer to that problem can be within a constant.

Comment: If you assume say $x(0)=0$ then you solve the equation and get $x(t)=\sqrt{-\log u(t,0)}$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Given you know that $x$ is positive...